# Stop emacs from opening window automatically

Tags: emacs

This question probably applies to other emacs modes than `haskell-mode`, since I assume emacs has got a general way of opening windows for automatically created buffers:

haskell-mode for emacs enables me to hit <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> to load the contents of the current buffer into a Haskell interactive session, which automatically causes emacs to open the buffer for the session in a split window in the current frame. Since I am running a setup with multiple emacs clients connected to a server, I really don't want to show the buffer in each open frame I've got. Is there a way to prevent emacs from doing this kind of thing?

Comment: And where do you want it to be shown?

Comment: It shouldn't be. If the buffer for the interactive system is just created in the background, I can place it in the frame/window I desire by myself.

Comment: The 'most correct' solution that I've found is posted [here](http://blog.mpacula.com/2012/01/28/howto-prevent-emacs-from-splitting-windows/). [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Window-Choice.html) is the relevant entry in the Emacs manual explaining how the variables and underlying process works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I found a solution just after posting this :).

Adding

```
(setq special-display-buffer-names
      '("*haskell*" "*Help*"))
```

to my .emacs tells emacs to open these buffers in a frame instead of a split.

Edit: But still, an even better solution would be for emacs never to create frames/splits automatically, but just silently create special buffers in the background. I can't figure out how to specify this though.

Comment: I don't know how to keep emacs from creating new frames, but the "-nw" switch will keep it from creating any frames at all, new or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

in  init.el

```
(setq split-height-threshold 5)
(setq split-width-threshold 5)
```